# What does Ign mean in update manager?

Tags: package-management, apt, update-manager, repository, software-sources

When I run update from the terminal, I get the following list where many repositories are shown with "Ign". Does it mean the update manager will always ignore updates from those repositories? Apart from some repositories that I've disabled manually, all others are checked in my software sources. I'd like to receive updates from many of those sources.

Below is the output of my apt-get update:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/544545/

Answer (score 4):

- `Ign` (Ignore) means that it will ignore the repo, if there is no change in a repo it will say `Ign`. Anyway it's nothing wrong, it is the way it should be. This simply indicates that nothing has changed in that repository since you last checked.
- A `Hit` just means that it did a request, and found out that the file hadn't been updated.

Comment: That means if there are any changes or available in any of those repos, it will be Hit instead of Ign and notify me of the updates?

Comment: 'Hit' means no updates are available.